# Django: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I want to sum all the fields of a model by using aggregate(sum()) function but getting this error.

**Views.py**

```
def paymentdailyreport(request):
    cashsum= Payment.objects.filter(PaymentMethod="Cash").aggregate(sum('Amount'))
    print(cashsum)
    context={

    }
    return render(request,'paymentdailyreport.html',context)
```

**Models.py**

```
 class Payment(models.Model):
        Date=models.CharField(max_length=20)
        User=models.CharField(max_length=50)
        PatientName=models.CharField(max_length=50)
        Dentist=models.CharField(max_length=50)
        Scheme=models.CharField(max_length=50)
        PaymentMethod=models.CharField(max_length=50)
        Amount=models.DecimalField(max_digits=20,decimal_places=3)
        def __str__(self):
            return self.Date + " | " + self.User + " | " + self.PatientName
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not use the builtin `sum` to sum up the values: you specify to determine the sum with a [**`Sum`** expression [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#sum):

```
from django.db.models import Sum

def paymentdailyreport(request):
    #                                         use Sum instead of sum ↓
    cashsum= Payment.objects.filter(PaymentMethod="Cash").aggregate(Sum('Amount'))
    print(cashsum)
    context={
        'cashsum': cashsum
    }
    return render(request,'paymentdailyreport.html',context)
```

Comment: it says "Name Sum is not defined"

Comment: @ZPro: you need to import it, as is written at the top of the code fragment...

Comment: OK, I got the point